# Building a Generator with Tensorflow 2.3 for array shape (200, )

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am having trouble finding a Generator architecture for a simple array.

The ideas is the following,

- Generator takes the encoded input from the auto-encoder *(trained earlier)* which outputs an array of shape `(200,)`.

My current generator Model:

```
def Generator():
    input_layer = Input(shape=[200]) #(bs, 200)
    d1 = Dense(165, activation = 'relu')(input_layer)
    d2 = Dense(140, activation = 'relu')(d1)
    d3 = Dense(100, activation = 'relu')(d2)
    d4 = Dense(50, activation = 'relu')(d3)
    d5 = Dense(25, activation = 'relu')(d4) #(bs, 25)
    up1 = Dense(50, activation = 'relu')(d5)
    cat = concatenate([up1,dense_4])
    up2 = Dense(100, activation = 'relu')(cat)
    cat = concatenate([up2, dense_3])
    up3 = Dense(140, activation = 'relu')(cat)
    cat = concatenate([up3, dense_2])
    up4 = Dense(165, activation='relu')(cat)
    cat = concatenate([up4, dense_1])
    last = Dense(200, activation = 'relu')(cat)
    return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs=last)
```

The train steps, losses and [cycleGAN tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cyclegan) are same.

Since I am using this generator for a cycle-GAN project, I thought i would get good results after 100 epochs, but it was the opposite.

I used a Generator without *skip connections* but the results were much worse than the one above.

I searched for RES-Net and U-Net Architecture but since they require Convolutional layers, I haven't tried them yet.

**My Questions**:

1. What recommendations do you have?
2. What type of skips connections should I use *(add or concatenate)*?

Comment: Don't you think there are too many `Dense` layers. You can try reducing 2 `Dense` layers from down and up. Also put some `Dropout` layers.

Comment: @AbhilashAwasthi Okay, I will notify you if results are ok or not, since training takes a long time

Comment: @AbhilashAwasthi Doesn't work, after few epochs went by it would still show one gray image.